# how to make a field have choices from another model in django

Tags: django, model

I am creating a gradeviewing app for my School Project and I am confused on how do I need to build relationships of each models.

I want a `subject` field on my `StudentGrade` model to have a list of choices coming from `Student` model but I only want to display/get the `enrolled_subjects` of the `student instance`

model.py:

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
        subject_name = models.CharField(...)
        subject_code =  ...
        ...


class Student(models.Model):
        student = models.ForeignKey(setttings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,...)
        enrolled_subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subjects)
        ...


class StudentGrade(models.Model):
    PERIOD_CHOICES = [
        ...
    ]

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=Q(is_student=True))
    period = models.CharField(choices=PERIOD_CHOICES, max_length=25)
    subject = // i want this to be list of subjects that the student has enrolled
    grade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
```

on the `StudentGrade` model, I want the `subject` field to be based on the `enrolled_subjects` of `student instance` how can I do that?

Comment: You have to do this in your form/serializer

Comment: so what should i do with my `subject` field on `Student Model`? should i just make it `models.CharField()`? @bdbd

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, why not put subjects inside `StudentGrade` as a m2m, and remove it from `Student`? So you can access a student's subjects via `StudentGrade` which makes sense, since subjects depend on grade/period. Also if `StudentGrade.user` is the student, you can use `Student` as the FK instead of `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` right?

Comment: The easiest way I will suggest use django formsets. You can use formsets for combine multiple models fields in a single forms in your views.   you can read more about formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize a ["through"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) table on your M2M. Your `StudentGrade` model can act as the intermediary table.

```py
class Student(models.Model):
        student = models.ForeignKey(setttings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,...)
        enrolled_subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subjects, through="StudentGrade")

class StudentGrade(models.Model):
    PERIOD_CHOICES = [
        ...
    ]

    user = models.ForeignKey("Student", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey("Subjects", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    period = models.CharField(choices=PERIOD_CHOICES, max_length=25)
    grade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
```